# Cross-validating KNN using K-fold

Tags: r, cross-validation, knn, k-fold

When using KNN to predict price how do you use K-fold to cross-validate?
My current code to predict is

```
library("tidyverse")
library("FNN")
library("forecast")
library("caret")
library("stats")


houses=read_csv("data.csv")
houses = subset(houses, price < 1000001)
houses = subset(houses, price >99999)
houses = subset(houses, price != 0)


houses =houses %>%
  select(-street,-city, -statezip,-country)


houses = houses %>%
  mutate(date = as.Date(houses$date)) %>%
  mutate(date = format(date, format="%Y"))

houses = houses %>%
  mutate(date = as.numeric(houses$date)) %>%
  mutate(yr_built = as.numeric(houses$yr_built)) %>%
  mutate(age_when_listed = date - yr_built)

houses = houses %>%
  mutate(age_when_listed = (houses$date - houses$yr_built))


houses= houses %>%
  mutate(renovated = ifelse(yr_renovated > 0, 1,0))



b1= mean(houses$bedrooms)
b2=sd(houses$bedrooms)

c1= mean(houses$bathrooms)
c2=sd(houses$bathrooms)

e1= mean(houses$sqft_lot)
e2=sd(houses$sqft_lot)

f1= mean(houses$floors)
f2=sd(houses$floors)

g1= mean(houses$view)
g2=sd(houses$view)

h1=mean(houses$waterfront)
h2=sd(houses$waterfront)

i1= mean(houses$condition)
i2=sd(houses$condition)

j1= mean(houses$sqft_above)
j2=sd(houses$sqft_above)

k1= mean(houses$sqft_basement)
k2=sd(houses$sqft_basement)

l1= mean(houses$age_when_listed)
l2=sd(houses$age_when_listed)

m1=mean(houses$yr_renovated)
m2=sd(houses$yr_renovated)


houses = houses %>%
  mutate(bedrooms_norm = (bedrooms-b1)/b2,bathrooms_norm = (bathrooms-c1)/c2,
         sqft_lot_norm = (sqft_lot-e1)/e2,floors_norm = (floors-f1)/f2,
         view_norm = (view-g1)/g2, condition_norm = (condition-i1)/i2,
         sqft_above_norm = (sqft_above-j1)/j2, sqft_basement_norm = (sqft_basement-k1)/k2,
         age_when_listed_norm = (age_when_listed-l1)/l2, waterfront_norm=(waterfront-h1)/h2,
         yr_renovated_norm=(yr_renovated-m1)/m2)

houses_input_norm = houses %>%
  select(bedrooms_norm, bathrooms_norm, 
         sqft_lot_norm, floors_norm, view_norm,condition_norm, sqft_above_norm,
         sqft_basement_norm, age_when_listed_norm, waterfront_norm, yr_renovated_norm)

#New sample observation
newdata= as_tibble(list(bedrooms=4,bathrooms=3, sqft_lot=2000,floors=2, waterfront= 0,
                        view=2, condition=3,sqft_above = 3000,sqft_basement=0,age_when_listed=20, yr_renovated=0))

newdata = newdata %>%
  mutate(bedrooms_norm = (bedrooms-b1)/b2,bathrooms_norm = (bathrooms-c1)/c2,
         sqft_lot_norm = (sqft_lot-e1)/e2,floors_norm = (floors-f1)/f2,
         view_norm = (view-g1)/g2, condition_norm = (condition-i1)/i2,
         sqft_above_norm = (sqft_above-j1)/j2, sqft_basement_norm = (sqft_basement-k1)/k2,
         age_when_listed_norm = (age_when_listed-l1)/l2,waterfront_norm=(waterfront-h1)/h2,
         yr_renovated_norm=(yr_renovated-m1)/m2)


newdata_input_norm = newdata %>%
  select(bedrooms_norm, bathrooms_norm, 
         sqft_lot_norm, floors_norm, view_norm,
         condition_norm, sqft_above_norm, sqft_basement_norm, 
         age_when_listed_norm,waterfront_norm, yr_renovated_norm)

houses_output= houses$price
```

Then to cross-validate I used this code (based on textbook example) does this only for cross validating linear regression problems or is it accurate for K-NN also?

```
set.seed(30)

houses = houses%>%
  tibble::rowid_to_column("ID")

temp =as_tibble()

houses = houses %>%
  mutate(fold = sample(1:10, 4202, replace = TRUE))

K=10
for(obs_num in 1:K)
{  
  train = houses %>%
    filter(ID != obs_num)
  
  validation= houses%>%
    filter(ID ==obs_num)
  
  train.mlr = lm(price~bedrooms + bathrooms + sqft_lot+floors+
                   view+ condition+sqft_above+ sqft_basement+ age_when_listed+
                 yr_renovated+ waterfront, train)
  
  validation = validation%>%
    mutate(price_prediction = predict(train.mlr, validation))
  
  am= accuracy(validation$price_prediction, validation$price)
  
  temp= temp %>%
    bind_rows(as_tibble(list(run=obs_num, RSME = am[2], MAPE= am[5])))
  print(paste("iteration", obs_num, "completed"), sep =" ")
  
}

temp %>%
  summarise(mean_MAPE = mean(MAPE), sd_MAPE = sd(MAPE))

temp %>%
  summarise(mean_RSME = mean(RSME), sd_RSME = sd(RSME))
```

Is this code accurate to cross validate using K-fold or do I need to change it, it outputs error levels currently but uncertain if they are correct

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look quite right to me at the moment. Within your cross validation loop you are assigning to your `train` and `validation` tables based on the `ID` variable. I think if you change this to be based on your `fold` variable instead, then it should work ok.

e.g.

```
K=10
for(obs_num in 1:K)
{  
  train = houses %>%
    filter(fold != obs_num)
  
  validation = houses%>%
    filter(fold == obs_num)
  
  train.mlr = lm(price~bedrooms + bathrooms + sqft_lot+floors+
                   view+ condition+sqft_above+ sqft_basement+ age_when_listed+
                 yr_renovated+ waterfront, train)
  
  validation = validation%>%
    mutate(price_prediction = predict(train.mlr, validation))
  
  am= accuracy(validation$price_prediction, validation$price)
  
  temp= temp %>%
    bind_rows(as_tibble(list(run=obs_num, RSME = am[2], MAPE= am[5])))
  print(paste("iteration", obs_num, "completed"), sep =" ")
  
}
```

It's generally fairly easy to adapt a cross-validation loop like this for different model types. The thing to check is that the `predict()` function still works the same way. `predict` is a wrapper for predicting using most model types - sometimes it required additional input arguments, and sometimes the outputs are in a different format.

Your KNN model is slightly more complicated, as the `FNN` package doesn't have a simple `predict` function built into it. It would have to look something like this:

```
K=10
for(obs_num in 1:K)
{  
  train = houses %>%
    filter(fold != obs_num) 
  
  # Select your predictors, and convert to a matrix. 
  train.matrix = train %>%
    select(bedrooms,bathrooms,sqft_lot,floors,
               view,condition,sqft_above,sqft_basement,age_when_listed,
             yr_renovated,waterfront) %>% as.matrix()
  
  validation = houses%>%
    filter(fold == obs_num)
  
  # Select your predictors, and convert to a matrix. 
  validation.matrix = validation %>%
    select(bedrooms,bathrooms,sqft_lot,floors,
               view,condition,sqft_above,sqft_basement,age_when_listed,
             yr_renovated,waterfront) %>% as.matrix()
  
  # Here k is set to 3, but you can set it to something else
  train.knn = FNN::knn(train.matrix, validation.matrix, train$price, k=3)
  
  validation = validation %>%
    mutate(price_prediction = train.knn[1:nrow(validation)])
  
  am= accuracy(validation$price_prediction, validation$price)
  
  temp= temp %>%
    bind_rows(as_tibble(list(run=obs_num, RSME = am[2], MAPE= am[5])))
  print(paste("iteration", obs_num, "completed"), sep =" ")
  
}
```

Of course, it's hard to tell if this works without seeing your data. Can you provide a sample of your data, or a reproducible example using a dataset available in R?  With the above code you will have to make sure that the format of `train.matrix` and `validation.matrix` match exactly. Also, note that `FNN` works with numeric data only - if you have any categorical predictors they will have to be one-hot-encoded first.